# JPA Mapping issue

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I have the following tables

```
CREATE TABLE APPUSERS (
    APPUSERS_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),  
    USERNAME VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
    PASSWORD VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (USERNAME)
);

CREATE TABLE ALL_ROLES (
    ROLE_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
    ROLENAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ROLENAME)
);

CREATE TABLE USER_ROLES(
  USER_ROLE_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
  USERNAME VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FK_USERNAME FOREIGN KEY (USERNAME)     
    REFERENCES APPUSERS (USERNAME),
    ROLENAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_ROLENAME FOREIGN KEY (ROLENAME)     
    REFERENCES ALL_ROLES (ROLENAME),
    PRIMARY KEY (username,rolename)
)
```

I have created the corresponding Entities(See below) and Repositories

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "appusers")
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String passwordConfirm;
    private Set<Role> roles;

    @Id
    @Column(name="APPUSERS_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Transient
    public String getPasswordConfirm() {
        return passwordConfirm;
    }

    public void setPasswordConfirm(String passwordConfirm) {
        this.passwordConfirm = passwordConfirm;
    }

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLES", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USERNAME"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROLENAME"))
    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
```

And

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "USER_ROLES")
public class Role {
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="USERNAME")
    private String name;
    private Set<User> users;

    @Id
    @Column(name="USER_ROLE_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

When I start the application I get the following error

```
Foreign key (FKrs04la1w0u7vtog85q1hxlse9:user_roles [rolename])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (user_roles [username,rolename])
```

I am not able to figure what what is the issue here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I think the table mappings are all correct but not sure why this error is occurring.

Comment: @K.Nicholas Can you please explain a bit more so that I can correct my mistake

Comment: I don't see any 'rolename' field in the third table but your constraint references it. It is complete?

Comment: @K.Nicholas Yes, its on line 6 of that query

Comment: You have username as the PK in the SQL but not in the User class. A join table for a manytomany has to have a PK from each of the other tables.

Comment: Okay, bad formatting on the SQL. Still, your JPA does not match the SQL for `PRIMARY KEY (USERNAME)`. I didn't look close at the ` @JoinTable` annotation but I think you need two `@JoinColumns` there but don't take my word for it. Look closer at that. The error message is good, it is saying you haven't set the `@JoinColumns` properly. Fix the `appusers` and remove the `@JoinTable` annotation to start with and it will get working. Look at the sql it generates and tailor as needed.

Comment: Your `User` class and table are inconsistent. If you have a generated field then that has to be `@Id` and hence PK in the table. You cannot just define some other field as PK in the table!

Comment: @K.Nicholas thanks, I will update these and let you know. I understood my mistakes here

Comment: @K.Nicholas  Got it working, removed those IDs and used the USERNAME and ROLENAME as primary keys and now I am able to map correctly. Thank you for your input. Appreciate it.

Comment: Great. The SQL still shows those identities `APPUSERS_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)` which is a little funny for a DB but no matter. You could probably reproduce those with an `@GeneratedValue` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues on your code, let me explain for steps:

1. Relationship many to many, you need to create an intermediate table in order to do that so you need to fix these following aspects:

   ```
   User entity

   @Id
   @Column(name = "APPUSERS_ID")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;     

   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
   private Set<Role> roles;    

   Role entity

   @Id
   @Column(name = "USER_ROLE_ID")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;

   @ManyToMany
   @JoinTable(name = "role_user",
           joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id") },
           inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") })
   private Set<User> users;
   ```
2. If you want these entities are generated on database by JPA hibernate just put the following property configuration(you just need to create database with name).

   spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
3. Else I leave you here scripts to execute on database.

   -- Table: public.appusers

   -- DROP TABLE public.appusers;

   ```
   CREATE TABLE public.appusers
   (
       appusers_id bigint NOT NULL,
       password character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
       password_confirm character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
       username character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
       CONSTRAINT appusers_pkey PRIMARY KEY (appusers_id)
   )
   WITH (
       OIDS = FALSE
   )
   TABLESPACE pg_default;

   ALTER TABLE public.appusers
       OWNER to postgres;
   ```

   -- Table: public.role_user

   -- DROP TABLE public.role_user;

   ```
   CREATE TABLE public.role_user
   (
       role_id bigint NOT NULL,
       user_id bigint NOT NULL,
       CONSTRAINT role_user_pkey PRIMARY KEY (role_id, user_id),
       CONSTRAINT fkma2afyyxc0mraogwivmj0klfe FOREIGN KEY (role_id)
           REFERENCES public.user_roles (user_role_id) MATCH SIMPLE
           ON UPDATE NO ACTION
           ON DELETE NO ACTION,
       CONSTRAINT fkmhbomge36ygro6rth9negs1ye FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
           REFERENCES public.appusers (appusers_id) MATCH SIMPLE
           ON UPDATE NO ACTION
           ON DELETE NO ACTION
   )
   WITH (
       OIDS = FALSE
   )
   TABLESPACE pg_default;

   ALTER TABLE public.role_user
       OWNER to postgres;
   ```

   -- Table: public.user_roles

   -- DROP TABLE public.user_roles;

   ```
   CREATE TABLE public.user_roles
   (
       user_role_id bigint NOT NULL,
       username character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
       CONSTRAINT user_roles_pkey PRIMARY KEY (user_role_id)
   )
   WITH (
       OIDS = FALSE
   )
   TABLESPACE pg_default;

   ALTER TABLE public.user_roles
       OWNER to postgres;
   ```